# Difference between the verbs “amener” and “emmener”, and also “emporter” and “apporter”?

Tags: usage, sens, verbes

I was under the impression that both *amener* and *emmener* mean "to take" someone somewhere.  I'm not sure how they differ in usage.

I started wondering after hearing the song *L'Homme Que J'Adore*, where the singer says:

> 1. L'homme de mes rêves m'**amène** sur une île

Or maybe it's really:

> 2. L'homme de mes rêves m'**emmène** sur une île

And how do *emporter* and *apporter* fit into this?

Comment: Merci de vouloir corriger le plusieurs erreurs que probablement j'ai faites :)

Comment: http://www.bertrandboutin.ca/Folder_151_Grammaire/N_a_amener.htm

Comment: Wasn't the song written by a non-native speaker? Note also that the foreign accent is so strong that there isn't a big difference between the sound of "amène" and "emmène". As others have stated, the correct usage is almost surely "emmène".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

« amener quelqu'un ou quelque chose quelque part » is « to take someone or something to somewhere » The emphasis is on the destination which is rarely omitted.

« emmener quelqu'un » is « to take someone with oneself ». The emphasis is on **with oneself**; the destination and the origin is often not mentioned and not important.  The dictionary of the Academy says « **Contrairement à** *Emporter*, **qui le plus souvent s'emploie avec des noms d'êtres inanimés**, *Emmener* **s'emploie uniquement avec des noms d'êtres animés.** » (in bold, and hinting that the usage in fact doesn't agree with them :-))

I now respond to your 1. « L'homme de mes rêves m'amène sur une île. »
and 2. « L'homme de mes rêves m'emmène sur une île. » :

In 1, what is important is that she reaches the island. In 2, what is important is that she goes there with the man of her dreams.  I can't listen to the song from here, but 2  is more probable.

Comment: emmener take someone with one, with you, with him, etc. No self. :)

Answer (score 16):

Tu pourrais trouver [cet article](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/vocabulary/to-take-to-bring/) intéressant. Je vais rapporter les informations plus important ici:

> The English verbs **to bring** and **to take** have four French equivalents: *amener, emmener, apporter, and emporter*. This causes all kinds of confusion, but it really is very simple once you understand the differences.

**To bring**

> The French verbs **apporter** and **amener** are used to indicate that you are bringing someone/something with you to the place where you are.

> **Apporter** can only be used with things you can carry, whereas **amener** has to be used with people, animals, and vehicles.

> - *J'ai amené mon frère à la fête.*  = I brought my brother to the party.

- *J'ai apporté mon livre à la fête.*  = I brought my book to the party.

**To take**

> **Emporter** and **emmener** are used to mean that you are taking someone/something to a different place than you are right now.

> **Emporter** is for things you can carry, while **emmener** is for people, animals, or vehicles.

> - *J'ai emmené mon frère à la fête.*   = I took my brother to the party.

- *J'ai emporté mon livre à la fête.*   = I took my book to the party.

---

> **Summary**
> [image]

Comment: Cette reponse est genial, merci :)

Comment: @Paolo De rien! :)

Comment: Bring and took don't imply if you're going to or from a place in English. Saying "I brought my computer with me" when discussing a trip I just took sounds perfectly fine to my ear.

Comment: @bronxbomber92 bring to where you are and take to where you are not, generally speaking. AmE speakers seem to use bring a lot for take. A parent says: Don't forget to take your bookbag with you. AmE speakers seem to usually say: Don't forget to bring your bookbag with you,  when they are in the same place as the kid., That's a mistake. If the parent is going to stay home, he/she should say: Take x with you. Not bring x with you.

Answer (score 5):

As the others said, it's a matter of reference according to whether you're considering the target or the destination:

> *Amène-moi ta sœur, je dois lui parler.*  (Bring your sister here, I need to talk to her: from there -> to here)
>
> *Emmène ta sœur au jardin zoologique.* (Take your sister to the zoo: from here -> to there)

If that's easier for you to grasp, the same distinction exists with *émigrer* (emmigrate) and *immigrer* (immigrate): both deal the concept of changing country (*migrer*), but *émigrer* is leaving one country, and *immigrer* is entering the other. While you do both at the same time, your country of origin will say you emmigrate while your country of destination will say you immigrate.

Again, since it's a matter of reference, the difference is subtle and can show which part you want to emphasize:

> *L'homme de mes rêves m'amène sur une île*

Puts the focus on the destination, so the island is what's important, while:

> *L'homme de mes rêves m'emmène sur une île*

Puts the focus on sweeping you away from where you are now, and the fact that it's to an island doesn't really matter. Considering the island is explicitely specified, and the source is not, I would tend to think the first makes more sense; but that's not to say the second is incorrect.

As for [the original song](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCMQtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6yad7AoNxU&ei=PqFUTtiXKorLswankon8Dw&usg=AFQjCNFk00JGk4DeLIggYu9risJ4mKhdzA), quite honestly I can't make it out for sure whether Alisson Adams Tucker says one or the other. Sure, the subtitle lyrics say *emmène* but that's just what whoever put the subtitles thought.

Answer (score 5):

Il y a quatre verbes : amener, apporter, emmener, emporter.

La différence entre *Emporter* et *Apporter* est la analogue à la différence, en anglais, entre *Go to* et *Come from* : il s’agit du point de vue. Si je suis chez moi et que je prends mon livre pour aller à l’université, je dis : « J’emporte le livre » ou « J’emmène le livre ». Si je suis à l'université, je dis : « J’ai apporté le livre » ou « J’ai amené le livre ». S’il y a une notion de restitution on peut dire « J’ai rapporté le livre que je vous ai emprunté ».

La différence entre *Emporter* et *Emmener* d'une part, et *Apporter* et *amener* d'autre part, est qu'on ne peut pas utiliser *emporter* ni *apporter* si ces verbes sont suivis par un objet animé, comme une personne.

Cet exemple est donc correct mis à part l'orthographe et la typographie :

> – Tu as mon livre avec toi ?
>   – Non, je te l’amène demain.

Comment: et inversement, emmener et amener ne s'utilisent pas avec des objets qu'on *porte*.

Comment: L’exemple est incorrect. On dit « je te l’apporte demain ». On _porte_ un livre, on _mène_ une vache.

Answer (score 4):

The two verbs are very similar and can often be used in the same context:

"Emmener" means to take out of the current place and to another place.

"Amener" means to take from one place to another, or to lead to another place.

Answer (score 3):

“Amener” is when you're talking about someone, or a pet, just like “emmener”. However, “amener” contains the idea of a destination, where as “emmener” contains the idea of a starting point.

So in your particular song, it would be appropriate to say “amène”, since you're going *to* the island.

Even though it's not a site dedicated to this kind of topic, you'll find more information on [that page](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/capsules/amener.htm).

Answer (score 3):

## Selecting the Base Verbs

#### Porter: Things

The verb “porter” means to carry, so it’s used with inanimate objects.

> Je porte ma valise. *I carry my suitcase.*
>
> J’emporte mon parapluie en voyage. *I’m bringing my umbrella on my trip.*
>
> J’apporte une bouteille chez mon ami. *I’m bringing a bottle to my friend’s house.*

#### Mener: Animal/Person

The verb “mener” means to lead, so it’s used with animate beings: people and animals.

> Napoléon mène ses armées. *Napoleon leads his armies.*
>
> J’emmène mon bébé au restaurant. *I’m bringing my infant to the restaurant.*
>
> J’amène ma fille à l’école. *I’m taking my daughter to school.*

---

## The Prefixes A-, Em-, Ra- and Rem-

Adding these prefixes to the “base verbs” porter and mener, we get:

**From *porter*:** apporter, emporter, rapporter and remporter

**From *mener*:** amener, emmener, ramener and remmener

Prefix + *porter* is used with things and inanimate objects.

Ex: *emporter*: to bring things

Prefix + *mener* is used with people and animals.

Ex: *amener* – to bring a person

#### Choosing the Right Prefix

Once you have selected your correct “base verb”, the question to ask is whether you are accompanying, staying with the person, or keeping the thing with you,
or if you are just dropping it/him/her, leaving it/him/her at destination.

Then, selecting the correct prefix will translate the notion of bring or take in French.

**A-**: you are going to leave the thing/person there. This is the idea behind “amener” and “apporter”.

**Em-**: you are staying with the thing/person. This is the idea behind “emmener” and “emporter”.

The prefixes **ra-** and **rem-** in French can mean any of:

– the repetition of an action

– the return to a point of departure

– the return of something to its normal place

---

This is an excerpt from a [French Today post](http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/amener-emmener-apporter-emporter-remporter-bring-take-french).

Answer (score 0):

1. « Amener » se dit pour le fait de diriger le déplacement de quelque chose d'un point à un autre au cours d'une action qui n'est consacré qu'à ce but particulier; le préfixe « a- » a le sens d'« exprimer une idée de passage d'un état à un autre,  ou de direction vers un lieu » (TLFi)

   - Lorsqu'elle part à son travail tous les matins elle **emmène** les enfants avec elle et elle les dépose à l'école. Tous les matins, après qu'il ait **amené** les enfants à l'école, il boit une bière. Le policier l'a **amené** à dire la vérité. Son père lui avait demandé des allumettes; après lui en avoir **amené** une boite il alluma deux cigarettes. Je t'**emmène** au cinéma demain, il faut voir ce film, il est surprenant. Je t'**amène** au cinéma dès que tu me le demande mais quelqu'un d'autre devra venir te chercher ou bien tu auras à prendre un taxi.
2. « Emmener » se dit pour le fait de faire prendre part à quelque chose ou à quelqu'un à un déplacement  mais pas nécessairement d'un point à un autre ;  l'idée dans ce verbe est que ce qui est emmené fait partie d'une ligne d'action mais n'est pas l'objet de l'action. Le sens du préfixe « en- », qui prend ici la forme spéciale « em- » en raison du m initial de la racine « mener », est défini comme étant celui d'« évoquer l'entrée dans un espace déterminé » (TLFi).

   - Il l'a **emmené** avec lui. Ces gens ont été **emmenés** dans des camps. Voici un wagon qui a servi à **amener** des prisonniers à Auschwitz. Lorsqu'on l'**emmène** au restaurant elle est heureuse. Je les **emmène** toujours lorsque je pars en voyage parce que ce sont les plus faciles à transporter.