# Amener et emporter

Tags: usage, sens, verbes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the verbs “amener” and “emmener”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/449/whats-the-difference-between-the-verbs-amener-and-emmener)

Quelle est la différence entre amener et emporter ?

Est-ce que cet exemple est correct ?

> - Tu as mon livre avec toi ?
> - Non, je te l'amène demain.

Comment: I know the question may not be an exact duplicate, but the answers will be, as evidenced from the first one we get.