# Comment le préfixe « en- » dans « emmener » explicite le champs sémantique de « emmener » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [ [Source](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2539) : ] *Emmener* signifie « faire quitter un lieu à un être animé en l'entraînant avec soi », sens qu'on peut confondre avec le premier sens du verbe *amener*. Contrairement au verbe *amener*, le verbe *emmener* met l'accent sur le point de départ, sur le lieu que l'on quitte et dont on s'éloigne, **idée qu'apporte le préfixe *em-* lorsqu'il est joint à un verbe de mouvement.** Lorsque le sujet du verbe *emmener* est une chose, il peut aussi signifier « conduire, transporter au loin ».
>
> [ [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emmener) : ] Attested in Old French as [enmener](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enmener#Old_French), equivalent to [en-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en-#French) +‎ [mener](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mener#French).

Je vous prie d'expliquer la proposition ci-dessous (en gras) qui affirme la question intitulée. En outre, comment le préfixe *en-* explique-t-il  [les différences](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/449/1995) entre « ammener » et « emmener » ?

Comment: Voir aussi [em-](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/em-) sur _TLFi_.

Answer (score 1):

***En*** : préposition marquant en général la position à l'intérieur de limites spatiales, temporelles ou notionnelles.<sup>1</sup>

- *Emmener, emporter* donne le point de vue d'une action à partir d'un point de départ.

> Emmène-moi ces vaches au champ

... elles sont à l'étable, à la position 'étable' leur action : quitter cet espace.

***A*** : marquant la direction. Lieu de destination.

- *Amener, apporter* donne le point de vue d'une action à son arrivée.

> Apporte-moi la table ici.

... porter un objet à l'endroit où il sera déposé.

---

<sup>Références tirées du petit Robert</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que la différence entre emmener et amener se perçoit d'autant moins facilement qu’ils sont oralement également facile à confondre (bien des jeunes et biens des gens doivent confondre).

Par contre la différence reste très claire en emporter et apporter.